# How to use JPA @Column(unique = true) in a multi-tenant environment?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, multi-tenant

I want to convert my application to support multi-tenancy using shared tables (i.e. every table gets a tenant id). Obviously, I would not be able to use `@Column(unique = true)` any more, because it would enforce uniqueness across all tenants, which I don't want.

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1 with EclipseLink. Is there a way make `@Column(unique = true)` force uniqueness per tenant (rather than per table). Or do I have to enforce this in the business logic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is also possible to specify uniqueness constraint on then `@Table`annotation, e.g.

```
@Table(name = "USERS", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"TENANT_ID", "username"}))
```

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink supports multi-tenancy using custom annotations (`@Multitenant`, `@TenantDiscriminatorColumn` and `@TenantDiscriminatorColumns`) or the equivalent attributes in `eclipselink-orm.xml` file, since [version 2.3.0](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337323). More information on how to use this supported feature is available in the [EclipseLink wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/Indigo/Multi-Tenancy); an [associated screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9JEuNn4wXk&feature=player_embedded) can be found on Youtube.

I would therefore assume that it is quite impossible to do so with the `@Unique` annotation alone.

Comment: I looked at the multi-tenancy support in EclipseLink before, but it looks like it doesn't support adding tenants at runtime. And if you look at the screencast, the app code is duplicated for every tenant. Therefore, I'm going to implement multi-tenancy support manually by adding the tenant ID into every column and query. Did u try multi-tenancy in eclipselink?

Comment: I haven't tried anything beyond the screencast, but if you look at the examples carefully, you can set the tenant Id (`eclipselink.tenant-id`) at runtime, if that is what you meant by adding tenants at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, it turned out you can set the property at runtime.